# Which CMS uses an ORM (Object-relational mapping)

Tags: wordpress, drupal, orm, content-management-system, joomla

If you're aware of a CMS that uses an ORM (either their own or one of the well-known ones), please list the CMS here with the name of the ORM it uses.

If you know that the CMS you use DOESN'T use ORM, please also say so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that neither Drupal nor Wordpress use ORM.  Drupal 6 has it's own database abstraction layer, which is switching to PDO with D7, but it's still not ORM.  Both WP and Drupal are built procedurally, and presumably an application should be built on an object oriented paradigm to take advantage of ORM.

Answer (score 3):

[Django-CMS](http://www.django-cms.org/) which is Python-based uses an ORM. It uses an ORM because it's based on the excellent [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) framework which uses ORM (cf. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software)).

[This Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software) lists many PHP-based systems that use ORM. But most of them are frameworks (not CMSs). For example, the CakePHP framework and the [Symfony](http://pookey.co.uk/wordpress/archives/20-doctrine-orm-and-symfony) framework which uses Doctrine ORM.

To find CMSs that use ORM, you may want to look for a CMS built with those frameworks that use ORM. [Wildflower CMS](http://wf.klevo.sk/) is build on CakePHP, and there's a [bunch of CMSs](http://www.symfonylab.com/symfony-cms-frameworks-comparison/) built on Symfony.

Comment: That's what I said "more frameworks (not fully CMS)". I've included them because they have some CMS extension plugins. i've added some in the post.

Comment: These are all built on the Django ORM: https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/cms/

Comment: Most of these are built on an ORM (SQLAlchemy, Django ORM, SQLObject) https://wiki.python.org/moin/ContentManagementSystems

Answer (score 1):

**Specially in PHP**

**ORM** based cms, i cant remember. i have been working in php  and working on various cms. But have not found popular ORM based cms.

**I think reason is simple**

ORM have extra learning curve, one cms become popular if it have less learning curve. Though many popular cms maintain security but same time they avoid using new things.

**WIKI**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#PHP

Answer (score 1):

[modx revolution](http://modxcms.com/about/team/jcoward/transforming-modx-oo-mvc-orm.html) uses xPDO

> xPDO provides raw data access using
>   native PDO8  extensions when
>   available, falling back to a PDO
>   emulation framework that works all the
>   way back to PHP 4.3.x. It provides a
>   very lightweight O/RM
>   (object-relational mapping) layer with
>   access performance similar to using
>   the current MODx DB API. With native
>   PDO performance naturally improving
>   upon that (it's a compiled PHP
>   extension written in C), the choice of
>   using PDO as the exclusive database
>   abstraction layer, turned out better
>   than I ever imagined.

Answer (score 0):

Webnodes CMS is based on an in-house developed ORM, with native support for CMS features like revisions, languages etc.

It is very fast, and has an intelligent and automatic cache.

It also excels at handling relations between objects, so you can basically model any type of data with the solution, so you can use it for any type of web application, not just publishing pages.

See more at the [Webnodes website](http://www.webnodes.com).

Disclosure: I work at Webnodes.

Answer (score 0):

Silverstripe supports ORM with CMS

Answer (score 0):

All Django based CMSs use an ORM cos Django uses it's own ORM.

The following are major Django based CMSs.

[Django CMS Official Website](https://www.django-cms.org/en/)

[Wagtail CMS Official Website](https://wagtail.io/)

[Mezzanine CMS official website](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/)

Django CMS seems to be the most popular of these three.

Wagtail follows a Lego block approach.

Here is a comparision of the three CMSs https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3UC1MNFOjEI